# Can't start payara server from Intellij - serverConfig is null. Payara Platform Tools exception

Tags: intellij-idea, payara

I am struggling with an error appearing when trying to run payara from inteliij. The problem appeared out of nowhere, one day in the evening the project worked without a problem, the next morning an error popped up.
The error appears in all projects, both old and newly created ones.

The application server itself works when run from the command line, but in intellij I get the error: "Error running Payara 6.2023.2": Cant invoke "org.jdom.Element.getChild(String) because "serverConfig" is null.

Here's stacktrace:

```
org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 552: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.jdom.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:191)
    at org.jdom.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:212)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:586)
    at com.intellij.util.JdomKt.loadDocumentAndKeepBoundaryWhitespace(jdom.kt:68)
    at com.intellij.javaee.util.JavaeeJdomUtil.loadDocument(JavaeeJdomUtil.java:21)
    at com.intellij.javaee.util.JavaeeJdomUtil.loadDocument(JavaeeJdomUtil.java:16)
    at fish.payara.server.config.PayaraDomainConfigProcessor.getServerConfig(PayaraDomainConfigProcessor.java:85)
    at fish.payara.server.config.PayaraDomainConfigProcessor.getJavaConfig(PayaraDomainConfigProcessor.java:156)
    at fish.payara.server.config.PayaraDebugConfig.update(PayaraDebugConfig.java:78)
    at fish.payara.server.config.PayaraDebugConfig.update(PayaraDebugConfig.java:38)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.util.CachedConfig.check(CachedConfig.java:48)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.util.CachedConfig.get(CachedConfig.java:28)
    at fish.payara.server.config.PayaraConfig.access$000(PayaraConfig.java:26)
    at fish.payara.server.config.PayaraConfig$PayaraConfigFactory.get(PayaraConfig.java:55)
    at fish.payara.server.config.PayaraDebugConfig.getPort(PayaraDebugConfig.java:96)
    at fish.payara.server.PayaraStartupPolicy.initSettings(PayaraStartupPolicy.java:84)
    at fish.payara.server.PayaraStartupPolicy.initSettings(PayaraStartupPolicy.java:32)
    at com.intellij.javaee.oss.server.JavaeeStartupPolicy$1.initRunnerSettings(JavaeeStartupPolicy.java:53)
    at com.intellij.javaee.appServers.run.localRun.ScriptInfo.initRunnerSettings(ScriptInfo.java:46)
    at com.intellij.javaee.appServers.run.configuration.view.RunnerSpecificLocalPanel.resetEditorFrom(RunnerSpecificLocalPanel.java:74)
    at com.intellij.javaee.appServers.run.configuration.view.RunnerSpecificLocalPanel.resetEditorFrom(RunnerSpecificLocalPanel.java:19)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.lambda$resetFrom$0(SettingsEditor.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.bulkUpdate(SettingsEditor.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.resetFrom(SettingsEditor.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditorWrapper.resetEditorFrom(SettingsEditorWrapper.java:25)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.CompositeSettingsEditor.resetEditorFrom(CompositeSettingsEditor.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.CompositeSettingsEditor.resetEditorFrom(CompositeSettingsEditor.java:44)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.resetEditorFrom(ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.java:107)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.resetEditorFrom(ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.java:27)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.lambda$resetFrom$0(SettingsEditor.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.bulkUpdate(SettingsEditor.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.resetFrom(SettingsEditor.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditorConfigurable.reset(SettingsEditorConfigurable.java:39)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.SingleConfigurationConfigurable.reset(SingleConfigurationConfigurable.java:183)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.SingleConfigurationConfigurable.editSettings(SingleConfigurationConfigurable.java:117)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable.createNewConfiguration(RunConfigurable.kt:872)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable.createNewConfiguration(RunConfigurable.kt:907)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable$MyToolbarAddAction$showAddPopup$popup$1.invoke(RunConfigurable.kt:949)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable$MyToolbarAddAction$showAddPopup$popup$1.invoke(RunConfigurable.kt:946)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable$MyToolbarAddAction.showAddPopup$lambda$0(RunConfigurable.kt:949)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.NewRunConfigurationPopup$5.onChosen(NewRunConfigurationPopup.java:251)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.tree.TreePopupImpl.handleSelect(TreePopupImpl.java:317)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.tree.TreePopupImpl$MyMouseListener.mousePressed(TreePopupImpl.java:267)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:288)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6653)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
    at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.processMouseEvent(Tree.java:424)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4572)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:790)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:763)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:760)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:666)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:614)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:68)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:349)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:994)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:994)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$4(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:191)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:236)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1080)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:741)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:466)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1675)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1633)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.EditRunConfigurationsAction.actionPerformed(EditRunConfigurationsAction.java:24)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:333)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:307)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:356)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:307)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.invokeAction(ActionUtil.java:532)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.performAction(ActionPopupStep.java:252)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.lambda$onChosen$1(ActionPopupStep.java:229)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.lambda$dispose$17(AbstractPopup.java:1618)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.lambda$doWhenFocusSettlesDown$3(FocusManagerImpl.java:172)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.EdtInvocationManager.invokeLaterIfNeeded(EdtInvocationManager.java:33)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.ifFocusEventsInTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.kt:187)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.executeWhenAllFocusEventsLeftTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.kt:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:162)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.dispose(AbstractPopup.java:1616)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.dispose(WizardPopup.java:165)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.dispose(ListPopupImpl.java:391)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionGroupPopup.dispose(PopupFactoryImpl.java:290)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.runWithTrace(ObjectTree.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:159)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:264)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:252)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.disposeAllParents(WizardPopup.java:273)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.disposePopup(ListPopupImpl.java:485)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.handleNextStep(ListPopupImpl.java:512)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl._handleSelect(ListPopupImpl.java:479)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.handleSelect(ListPopupImpl.java:426)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionGroupPopup.handleSelect(PopupFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyMouseListener.mouseReleased(ListPopupImpl.java:680)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6656)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyList.processMouseEvent(ListPopupImpl.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:790)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:763)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:760)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:666)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:614)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:569)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:68)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:349)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:348)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:994)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:994)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$4(IdeEventQueue.kt:343)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 552; columnNumber: 176; Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:306)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3101)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at org.jdom.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:173)
    ... 173 more
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:702)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:568)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1699)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanLiteral(XMLEntityScanner.java:1137)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:980)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:447)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:250)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2726)
    ... 182 more
```

I tried:

- using different versions of intellij and payara, same error every time.
- seting up paths in Startup server configuration (surprisingly, there is no startup script path nor port in debug section wehen error pops out)

I worked out that if I start and close the application server from the command line, after opening the project, I will be able to run payara from intellij once (then all paths including debug sections are automatically detected). Restarting the server or redeploy leads to the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to perform `File | Repair IDE`

Comment: Delete the [system directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory) when the IDE is closed. All your IDE settings except ["Local History"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html#location) will be preserved.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas! Unfortunately, none of these steps helped. 
What's more, I did a windows reinstallation  (W10pro current build: 19045.2965). On a freshly installed/downloaded ide/payara, the problem still exsists.